# Finding distance from a point to a set

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

What is $d_A(p)$, where $A := \{(x,y) \in R^2 : x^2 + y^2 = 1\} ?$  Find an explicit expression.  Also $p=(a, b) \in R^2$

This is a question from the book: Topology of metric spaces by S. Kumersan.

I really don't understand how to find the distance using the formula $d_A(x) = \inf \{d(x,y)$ $|$ $y \in A\}. $
Also, can anyone suggest a book where I can find more information regarding this topic?

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: what is $d(x,y)$ ? is it the euclidian metric ? Moreover, the way you defined $d_A(x)$ has no sense. It should rather be $\inf\{d(x,y)\mid y\in A\}$.

Comment: Have you tried drawing a picture?

Comment: Yes, it is the Euclidean metric.

Comment: Make a drawing of it, you will see closest point of $(a,b)$ on circle is $ \frac{(a,b)}{\sqrt{a^2 +b^2 } }$

Comment: That is the definition of the distance from a point to a set, but you don't necessarily use it directly to find the distance. For this problem, like already suggested, draw a picture, and use coordinate geometry.

Comment: You will probably find something like $d_A(p) = | ~\| p \|-1 ~|$